# How can I try to improve when my account is banned

Tags: discussion, post-ban, answer-quality

My Stack Overflow account is banned from answering questions.

I know it is due to my previous answers, which seem spam to the moderator.

However I would like to improve my answers to earn my reputation back, problem is they are not accepting my answers anymore.

So please let me know what I can do?

Comment: [Please read the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998) (yes, I know that's for questions, the same rules apply as far as I know).

Comment: When did you find this out? Your last answer was almost year ago.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There are probably more recent deleted answers.

Comment: @Anna might be... anyway I won't bother much based on the little I can see - doesn't look like "little over the edge" case anyway.

Comment: I got banned and can't **post answers**. How can I gain credit then? I have read the FAQ, but I can't find the answer there.

Comment: @Gal: Edit your existing answers to make them better.  If you rewrite all your bad answers, people will take off downvotes and your ban will go away also.

Comment: Is he banned for good? I would like to upvote him if he improved his answer just so he can start over again. I think it's reasonable if we don't over do it.